# Add watermark after tile in ImageMagick

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, watermark

I got this working code for tiling an image in ImageMagick:

```
convert D:\tile.jpg -resize 300x300 -write mpr:tiler +delete ^
   -size 900x900 tile:mpr:tiler -sharpen 0x2 D:\tiles.jpg
```

But now i found out that i need to add watermark in the same process. I got this working code for that:

```
tiles.jpg Wartermark.png -gravity southeast -geometry +0+0 -composite D:\tile-watermark.jpg
```

But how do i process those two in one line?

Comment: Try `convert D:\tile.jpg ... -sharpen 0x2 Wartermark.png -gravity southeast -geometry +0+0 -composite D:\tile-watermark.jpg`

Comment: Of course! I should have figured that out my self: so straight forward ;-) Thanks!